# Can't Reproduce a video stream with AVPlayerController

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a TableViewController and when I click any cell I call *prepareforsegue* function to load an *AVPlayerViewController* that should reproduce the stream passed through the same function. When I click on a tab the function is called right, the video player is displayed but it doesn't initialize the **urlCanale** variable.

```
class HomeController: UITableViewController {
...
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let nuovoCanale = URL(string: menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url!)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "riproduciCanale", sender: nuovoCanale)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "riproduciCanale"{
            if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? VideoPlayerController{
                nextViewController.urlCanale = sender as? URL //Or pass any values
                print("cambio canale")                
            }
        }
```

This is the AVPlayerViewController Code, the variable urlCanale everytime is null :

```
class VideoPlayerController: AVPlayerViewController {
    var urlCanale : URL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //super.viewDidLoad()
    if(urlCanale == nil){
        print("is nuuulllll")
        urlCanale = URL(string: "https://www.google.it")        
    }
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: urlCanale)
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    player?.play()     
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to uncomment super.viewDidLoad() That's a major bug you have to fix.

Comment: ok thank you,  I tried comment and uncomment way but i have the same problem

Comment: I know that that's not the bug but you need this line of code either way. Do NOT uncomment it.

Comment: Did you make sure that URL(string: menuItems[indexPath.row].stream_url!) is not nil

Comment: yes before write this post I verified printing the value